# Plotting binary 3d data with gnuplot from a C program

Tags: 3d, binary, gnuplot

I don't manage to plot my data with gnuplot when I store it as a binary. Plotting from an ASCII file works **without** problems. Here's my attempt:
First, save the data

```
// omitted
double *t = alloc_mat(row + 1, col + 1);
    for(x = 0; x < row + 1; x++)
        for(y = 0; y < col + 1; y++)
            if(!y && !x)
                t[0] = col + 1;
            else if(!x && y != 0)
                t[x * (col + 1) + y] = y - 1;
            else if(!y && x != 0)
                t[x * (col + 1) + y] = x - 1;
            else
                t[x * (col + 1) + y] = data[(x - 1) * col + y - 1];

writebin_double(fname, t, row + 1, col + 1);
free(t);
```

The code creates a structure like

```
N+1, y0,  y1,  y2,  y3,  ...  yN
x0,  z00, z01, z02, z03, ..., z0N
x1,  y10, ...
```

according to http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node330.html#binary_matrix

The function writebin_double is simply

```
void writebin_double(char *fname, double *data, int row, int col)
{
    // omitted
    FILE *outfile = fopen(fname, "w");
    // omitted
    fwrite(data, sizeof(double), row * col, outfile);
    fclose(outfile);
}
```

When trying to plot the data as

```
set xr [0:599] # an example
set yr [0:799]
splot 'plttmp.dat' binary matrix format='%double' using 1:2:3 w l palette t ''
```

it fails with "**Read grid of zero width**" which I don't understand in this case, as the grid is specified in the for loop. I also tried the binary general setting, but it didn't help and I got the same message.

Thanks for ideas!

PS: gnuplot 4.6.4 on Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit

Comment: Have you tried using `floats` instead of `double`? Possibly the `format` option isn't supported for this kind binary matrices, see also the [`binary.c`](http://gnuplot.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gnuplot/gnuplot/src/binary.c?revision=1.16&view=markup) source which is mentioned on the page you linked.

Comment: Yes, `floats` doesn't work, it's either `float` or `double`. In my case, it should read double. I really don't get what I'm doing wrong, since it's just the fact that the data is hold as binary produces this problem. I can provoke an output by `splot '%s' binary format='%double' w pm3d` but it gives me just a couple of weird lines.

Comment: No, I mean try to use a `float` array in you C-code instead of a `double` one and don't use the `format` specifier at all.

Comment: OK, tried it. The error then reads `File doesn't factorize into full matrix`. The plot command I changed to `splot '%s' binary matrix using 1:2:3`

Comment: Try setting `t[0] = col;` instead of setting it to `col +1`. The example in the documentation might be misleading. There the columns are number from 0 to N, so you have N+1 columns. In your case you have `col` columns.

Comment: Nope, still same error.

Comment: Added: printing the same data in an ASCII file and then calling `splot ... nonuniform matrix using ...` works without a problem. I assume that the binary file goes without any linefeeds etc?

Comment: Could you then please add the definition of `alloc_mat` and combine all your snippets to a small, compileable program which we can use for testing? That would simplify debugging.

Comment: At last, it works. Your second suggesting did the trick. Though, it *only* works on my Ubuntu system. My last replies had been negative since I used a Windows 7 system. Now I'm back on Ubuntu and it works. Though, again, what is working on Ubuntu is not working on Windows. That's so far fine with me. If there's still the necessity, I can try to work out a simple example.

Comment: I think it would be nice if you could provide the simple example to help others. Maybe someone also finds the reason why it doesn't work on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to the problem: gnuplot takes only single precision floating point numbers in the binary format, as Christoph pointed out.

However, the plotting of binary data in this format only works on Ubuntu, not on Windows. My systems:
Windows 7 64 bit, gnuplot 4.6.5 ||
Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, gnuplot 4.6.4

Here's the minimum working example:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef unsigned int uint;

void wdata_ascii(const char *fname, const double *data, const uint row, const uint col)
{
    FILE *wfile = fopen(fname, "w");
    uint x, y;
    for(x = 0; x < row + 1; x++)
        for(y = 0; y < col + 1; y++)
        {
            if(!y && !x)
                fprintf(wfile, "%u", col);
            else if(!x && y != 0)
                fprintf(wfile, "%u", y - 1);
            else if(!y && x != 0)
                fprintf(wfile, "%u", x - 1);
            else
                fprintf(wfile, "%g", data[(x - 1) * col + y - 1]);

            if(y == col)
                fprintf(wfile, "\n");
            else
                fprintf(wfile, " ");
        }
    fclose(wfile);
}

void wdata_bin(const char *fname, const double *data, const uint row, const uint col)
{
    uint x, y;
    float *tsp = (float *)malloc((row + 1) * (col + 1) * sizeof(float));

    for(x = 0; x < row + 1; x++)
        for(y = 0; y < col + 1; y++)
            if(!y && !x)
                tsp[0] = col;
            else if(!x && y != 0)
                tsp[x * (col + 1) + y] = y - 1;
            else if(!y && x != 0)
                tsp[x * (col + 1) + y] = x - 1;
            else
                tsp[x * (col + 1) + y] = (float)data[(x - 1) * col + y - 1];

    FILE *outfile = fopen(fname, "w");
    fwrite(tsp, sizeof(float), (row + 1) * (col + 1), outfile);
    fclose(outfile);
    free(tsp);
}

void plotdata(const double *data, const uint row, const uint col)
{
    char *tmpdat = "pltdat",
         *cmdtmp = "pltcmd";

    fprintf(stdout,
            "\nthis will create or overwrite the files '%s' and '%s'. press enter to continue.\n",
            tmpdat, cmdtmp);
    getchar();

//  wdata_bin(tmpdat, data, row, col);
    wdata_ascii(tmpdat, data, row, col);

    FILE *gnufile = fopen(cmdtmp, "w");

    fprintf(gnufile,
            "set term png size 1024, 768\n" \
            "set yl 'y'\n" \
            "set xl 'x'\n" \
            "set out 'test.png'\n" \
            "#splot '%s' binary matrix using 2:1:3 w pm3d palette t ''\n"
            "splot '%s' nonuniform matrix u 2:1:3 w pm3d palette t ''\n",
            tmpdat, tmpdat);

    fclose(gnufile);
    system("gnuplot pltcmd");
    remove(tmpdat);
    remove(cmdtmp);
}

int main(void)
{
    uint x, y,
         row = 100, col = 200;
    double *dat = (double *)malloc(row * col * sizeof(double));

    for(x = 0; x < row; x++)
        for(y = 0; y < col; y++)
            dat[x * col + y] = (double)(x << 1) * y / 100.;

    plotdata(dat, row, col);
    free(dat);
    return 0;
}
```

I've removed any kind of validity checks, but it might also help people looking for a direct plotting of data within a C program via gnuplot. To check the described problem, switch between `wdata_ascii` and `wdata_bin` and also toogle between the `splot` lines (just change the `#` tag).